# Is it possible to store a set or other datastructures as a session variable in express sessions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express-session

I try to save a set in the session variable:

```
                var rowLength = result.rows.length;
                var setOfPermissions = new Set();
                for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
                    var permission = result.rows[i].permission;
                    setOfPermissions.add(permission);
                }

                req.session.permissions = setOfPermissions;
```

But later on when I try to access it:

```
    var setOfPermissions = req.session.permissions;
    if(setOfPermissions.has('my permission')) //Error over here
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: setOfPermissions.has is not a function

EDIT: The output of         console.log("permissions:::"+ setOfPermissions);
 is:

> permissions:::[object Object]

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof req.session.permissions)` return just above the if statement? It does look like it's getting converted into an object though.

Comment: @agm1984 It prints: permissions:::[object Object]

Comment: Everything sees okay. I think that you try to check for value before Set initialization.

Comment: Sessions typically get stored as JSON, and a `Set` can't be serialized to JSON directly.

Comment: @robertklep So are you saying that instead of storing my values in a set I should use some other structure ? What would you recommend ? An array ?

Comment: @KaizerSozay or an object (`if ('my permission' in setOfPermissions) { ... }`). I checked to see if `express-session` has an option to override the (de-)serialization methods, but it doesn't look like it has.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are stored in JSON, so when you assign a Set to the session object, it will be transferred to JSON, and when you access to retrieve it, the JSON will be parsed to an object or an array, which by the way, doesn't have a `has()` method.

Comment: So how do you convert the JSON back to a Set ?

Comment: Why would I want to do that? My point is, sessions should only store simple data, like a user ID, a user name, etc.

Comment: Using a set (of related data), such as a set of permissions makes it easy to check. Otherwise I need to check things another way. Its just a matter of convenience.

Comment: You can store a set in an object, with a unique key, and store this key in session, when the next request retrieve the session, then use the key to retrieve the set.